# Javascript: Change word colors depending on the word?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, background-color

I want to change the background color of words in a sentence depending on what the word is.

I want the user to be able to enter words like with a text area, but text areas don't support word background colors.

At the moment I can only think of bootleg solutions such as this:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");

function highlight() {
  var words = div.textContent.split(" ");
  div.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === "good") {
      div.innerHTML += "<span style=\"background-color: green;\">" + words[i] + "</span> ";
    } else if (words[i] === "bad") {
      div.innerHTML += "<span style=\"background-color: red;\">" + words[i] + "</span> ";
    } else {
      div.innerHTML += "<span>" + words[i] + "</span> ";
    }
  }
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(div.lastChild, 1);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
};
div.addEventListener("input", highlight);
highlight();
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  height: 128px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" contenteditable="true">good and bad colors</div>
```

The word 'good' gets a green background, and the word 'bad' gets a red background.

However, this is very glitchy and horrible, so I'm hoping there is a better way do do this.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using array methods instead, they're far nicer to work with than `for` loops:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("div");
function highlight() {
  const words = div.textContent.split(" ");
  div.innerHTML = "";
  words.forEach((word) => {
    const span = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
    span.textContent = word + ' ';
    if (word === 'good') span.classList.add('green');
    if (word === 'bad') span.classList.add('red');
  });
};
div.addEventListener("blur", highlight);
highlight();
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  height: 128px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" contenteditable="true">good and bad colors</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm really just looking for a better way entirely. I feel that using a div and adding spans in such a way is just wrong, no matter if I use array methods or not. Also, with my awful method, you have to manually move the selection to the end of the text so you don't type backwards.

Comment: Working with live `contenteditable` is quite a pain - I wouldn't recommend it at all. Consider using a standard input instead, with a results element, or something of the sort.

Comment: I'll probably end up adding the colors on blur like you're doing, but think of it like a code editor. Variables get highlighted in different colors live. I can't really add a results element although I'd love to, because it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: You could try using a *plain* div with an event listener. When keys are pressed, change a variable corresponding to the text, and update the div accordingly. When arrow keys are pressed, increment/decrement the index (current text cursor position) accordingly. On every index change (or new letter added/removed), recalculate the position of the text cursor, and make it visible at the appropriate location in the div somehow.